# ActiveMQ Artemis: One Producer with Two Consumers, only one consumer received message (most of the time), why?

Tags: jakarta-ee, server, cluster-computing, activemq-artemis

I have this, one producer, two consumers, all same queue. 
sometimes consumer0 and consumer1 DO able to receive messages consecutively, 
but most of the time only consumer0 receive half of the message, 
consumer1 always receive null value. 
why is this the case, or if there is any setting is wrong. 
(on one window machine, two brokers runned on two cmd. third cmd is to hit 
mvn spring-boot:run)

pushed to https://github.com/ren2046/artemis see if anyone could help?

Comment: Can you work up a reproducible test-case (e.g. based on one of the clustered examples shipped with Apache ActiveMQ Artemis) and push it to GitHub?  That would be much simpler to investigate than a bunch of cut and pasted code and xml.

Comment: pushed to this https://github.com/ren2046/artemis
see if anyone can help?

Comment: There's no documentation on how to run the test, apparently no automation, broker executables are Windows specific, generated files like logs and journal are committed to the repo.  I recommend you take a look at the examples shipped with the broker and base yours on one of those.  With a single command (i.e. 'mvn verify') the example will create & configure broker instances, start them, run the test, and then shut everything down again.